# How to see what process is running behind a port

Tags: powershell

I love PowerShell. It's my first scripting language and I find myself wanting to know more. As such, I'm interested in setting up a status page that reflects the state of specific programs behind a given port.

For example, coffeemug.exe runs on a local machine through port 60132.
How can I remotely see the process behind the port from the server hosting the status page?

On the local host (application server), that's easy to see via PS:

```
PS C:\> $AppPortID = ( Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 60132 ).OwningProcess
PS C:\> $AppPortID
2776
PS C:\> ( Get-WmiObject win32_process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessID -eq $AppPortID} ).ProcessName
coffeemug.exe
```

Remotely, however, I have yet to identify a way to achieve this. Through the cmdlet `Test-NetConnection` I can identify the open port, but I cannot for the life of me find a way to exploit the service/process running on said port.
Any ideas?

What I have so far with `Test-NetConnection`:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName application.domain.com -Port 60132 -InformationLevel Detailed
```

::EDIT::

I should have been more specific. I would like to be able to do this remotely, without using an invoke-command or something similar. Much like you can ping a random server.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke command worked for me,if i understood the question correctly

```
$processid = invoke-command -computername 'remote' -scriptblock {
    Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 1433)
    }
```

Get-wmiobject has  a property called computername ,so you can do below

```
get-wmiobject -computername 'remote' -processid $processid
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. Updated the text under ::EDIT::